# Google Sheets sum multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’ve just inherited a google sheet from a client where they’ve put multiple campaign performance data tables next to each other in a single sheet. I need to sum up the metrics into another sheet. The problem is that there are around 107 campaigns currently active and if I start summing them up the regular way with something like `=sum(A2,D2,G2,etc)` it’ll take me a long time to get it done AND there would be no guarantee of accuracy.

I’ve made some sample data which looks like my client data. Link to sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DtcYbkdHgcOH-IzEaD4UsWT2upujx8qD4AC8LErlM-U/edit?usp=sharing

In the data tab, I have a sample of the campaign data. You can see that there are multiple sections where each section represents a campaign. In the consolidated sheet, I’ve shown the end result that I need to work towards - a daily summary of all campaign data.

I need a solution which will scale up to 107 campaigns whose data is recorded in this one single sheet in a similar format. I appreciate any help that I can get with this project!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Query formula to get the desired output:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({Data!B4:F6;Data!H4:L6;Data!N4:R6}), "SELECT Col1, Sum(Col2), Sum(Col3), Sum(Col4) GROUP BY Col1 ")`

I have only added 3 tables as example, you can add more as required

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I though about using query but is there anyway to simplify adding 107 tables to this solution? My problem here is a problem of scale. There are way too many tables to add manually!

Comment: I'm afraid this is the best way using formula's. Now, If you'd like to use [Script Editor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), that's a different scenario